# Php url handling -urlencode not working -Stirng to url -special charater handling

Tags: php, string, url, encoding

```
String  = "KOA Axial Carbon Film Resistor 3.3k? ±5% 0.25W -450 ? +350ppm/°C"
```

Error link after encode

```
http://www.api.simplyduty.com/api/Classification/get-hscode?APIKey=A36AFAA1-A570-4279-84CC-ECE4B9EB76F6&fullDescription=KOA+Axial+Carbon+Film+Resistor+3.3k%CE%A9+%C2%B15%25+0.25W+-450+%E2%86%92+%2B350ppm%2F%C2%B0C&originCountry=AM&destinationCountry=AW
```

but i want  this type of conversion as browser do conversion

```
http://www.api.simplyduty.com/api/Classification/get-hscode?APIKey=A36AFAA1-A570-4279-84CC-ECE4B9EB76F6&fullDescription=KOA%20Axial%20Carbon%20Film%20Resistor%203.3k?%20%C2%B15%%200.25W%20-450%20?%20+350ppm/%C2%B0C&originCountry=AM&destinationCountry=AW
```

correct string how can i get this

```
"KOA%20Axial%20Carbon%20Film%20Resistor%203.3k?%20%C2%B15%%200.25W%20-450%20?%20+350ppm/%C2%B0C"
```

Comment: `+` and `%20` are both ways to encode space in a URL.

Comment: There's no error in your first result.

Comment: you can add something like this `$Something = str_replace('+','%20',$URLString);`

Comment: You can try working with base64 encoding

Comment: my string contain "ppm/"  how to do handling

Comment: your "correct" string forgets to encode the "?" and the "/" and "%" and "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at http://php.net/rawurlencode

```
php -r "echo rawurlencode('KOA Axial Carbon Film Resistor 3.3k? ±5% 0.25W -450 ? +350ppm/°C');"
KOA%20Axial%20Carbon%20Film%20Resistor%203.3k%3F%20%C2%B15%25%200.25W%20-450%20%3F%20%2B350ppm%2F%C2%B0C
```

Warning, your expected "correct" string forgets to encode 4 chars : / % ? +

the slash is encoded by "%2F", the "%" is encoded by "%25", the "?" is encoded by "%3F", the "+" is encoded by "%2B"

So you can obtain your expected string like this:

```
php -r "echo str_replace(['%2F', '%25', '%3F', '%2B'], ['/', '%', '?', '+'],  rawurlencode('KOA Axial Carbon Film Resistor 3.3k? ±5% 0.25W -450 ? +350ppm/°C'));"
KOA%20Axial%20Carbon%20Film%20Resistor%203.3k?%20%C2%B15%%200.25W%20-450%20?%20+350ppm/%C2%B0C
```

Comment: so how can i get this "KOA%20Axial%20Carbon%20Film%20Resistor%203.3k?%20%C2%B15%%200.25W%20-450%20?%20+350ppm/%C2%B0C" any other way

Comment: I have edited my answer, but I don't understand why you expect this string